# How create TortoiseGit branche for only need files?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have next folder structure:

```
mySolution/
 |--.git/
 |--dirA/
 |--dirB/
```

I wont to create branch **dirABranch** for only **dirA**, so I create branch and commit from context menu of this dirA, and add not-versioned files. But if I checkout for **Master** or for **dirABranch**, all solution restore state from that revision. But I want only dirA! Also I found some bug/unexpected behaviour if checkout from context menu of files in subdirectories.
I use last Git,TortoiseGit on win7

Comment: To work only with it in any other "main" branches. E.g. I have Stable and Experimental branches and "sub"-branches for Lo- and Hi-quality resources that can be used and with Stable and with Experimental.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this using one repository in git. The idea is that in git, a repository is always used as a whole.

Your best option is to split the repository in two. The second one will be only dirA and you include it into the main repository using as a [submodule](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html).